# Django - unit test AssertionError: 302 != 200, decorator problem

Tags: django, django-tests

I'm trying to write tests for my django app. The tests are failing because I'm getting 302 errors. For CBV I used have a decorator.py file that checks that the user `is_teacher`.  I believe that this is what is causing the problem.

view

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class ClassroomList(ListView):
    model = Classroom

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Classroom.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('classroom_name')
```

model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

test.py

```
class GradebookTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='tester',
            email='tester@email.com',
            password='tester123'
        )
        self.user.is_active = True
        self.user.is_teacher = True

    def test_classroomgradebook(self):
        self.client.login(username='tester', password='tester123')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('gradebook:gradebookstart'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, 'Choose the gradebook')
        self.assertNotContains(response, 'Enter')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'gradebook/classroom_list.html')
```

decorator.py

```
def teacher_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='login'):

    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_teacher,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

If I remove the `@method_decorator...` from the view, the test passes.

Comment: In `setUp` you haven't saved the user after setting the flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Brian Destur* mentioned, you need to call the **`save()`** method of the model to commit the changes to the DB

```
class GradebookTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='tester',
            email='tester@email.com',
            password='tester123'
        )
        self.user.is_active = True
        self.user.is_teacher = True
        self.user.save()  # Save the changes to DB

    # your code
```